# How to find what Variable is assigned to a value in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

If I have an array :

```
A1=100 ; 
A2=200 ; 
A3=300 ; 
A4=500 ;  
A=[A1 A2 A3 A4];
```

`A(2)` will give a value of `200.`

But how can I find out that `A(2)=A2` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[row,col]=find(A==200);

Answer:
row=2 -> Corresponds to A2
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: A will be an array of numbers. So if you do `find(A==A2)`, you will first have to define `A2=200` which boils down to the same expression.